# How to add div with id if my check box is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have my dynamic table with table cell where I created chekbox input. That check box switch the text available and blocked depends if it's checked or not. Now I would like to add div with id that will show up each time when I click on the check box. Problem is if I click on the check box now, my div will show up just on the first row, not on the row where I clicked on. Here is my code:

```
<tr class="blockRow">
   <td>
       <cfif qryTable.UserID EQ 0>
           <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="stop" id="stop" onChange="updateTable('#TimeID#')" checked>
             <span>Blocked</span>
           </label>
       </cfif>
       <cfif qryTable.UserID EQ -1>
           <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="stop" id="stop" onChange="updateTable('#TimeID#')">
                <span>Available</span>
           </label>
       </cfif>
       <div id="message"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    $('label').on('change', function() {
         var checked = $('input', this).is(':checked');
         $('span', this).text(checked ? 'Blocked' : 'Available');
    });
});
```

How I can include my div on the bottom with id=message to show up each time after I click on the check box? If anyone can help please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    $('label').on('change', function() {
         var checked = $('input', this).is(':checked');
         $('span', this).text(checked ? 'Blocked' : 'Available');
        });

    // Add one DIV (with ID message) after "cfif" closest to the element clicked
    $(this).closest('cfif').after('<div id="message">my message</div>');

    // The timeout is for remove the message after 1sec
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('#message').remove();
    }, 1000);

});
```

[Here the test on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/do0vdyy9/)

Note: Are you really sure that your logic requires you to initialize an event "onchange" in another event "onchange" ? You can use console.log("fire event") to check if the logic work properly.

**UPDATE: This is the correct answer**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    $('label').on('change', function() {
         var checked = $('input', this).is(':checked');
         $('span', this).text(checked ? 'Blocked' : 'Available');
        });

    $(this).closest('td').append('<div id="message" class="allmessage">my message</div>');

    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.allmessage').remove();
    }, 1000);

});
```

[And this is the correct live example of JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/do0vdyy9/2/)

Comment: I tried this but still my div shows up only on the first row.

Comment: There's probably something I do not understand. The lines are "TR" and in your example you have a single cell "TD", then duplicating the the lines "TR" in the HTML example , this is the result you want?  https://jsfiddle.net/do0vdyy9/2/

Comment: I want to apologize for not completely clear question. Yes this solved my problem actually. Now my div shows up next to the td where I clicked on and disappear after few seconds. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  
                $("#kcd").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("#kcddiv").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#kcddiv").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
body
            {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
            .container{
                margin:5% 20% 20% 10%;
                width:500px;
                height:200px;
                background-color:#C9EAF5;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <label for="kcd">
            <input type="checkbox" id="kcd" />
            Do you Want show div after check?
        </label>
        <hr />
        <div id="kcddiv" style="display: none">
            Your new div has appended
            <input type="text" id="kcdnum" />
        </div>
        </div>
```